# When I tavel from Papua new Guinea to US, do I need both a Visa and a Passport?

Tags: visas, usa, papua-new-guinea

I am trying to travel overseas from Papua New Guinea to USA. What permit do I need, is it visa or passport? Or do I need both to make my trip there?

Comment: Why have you tagged your question 'Canada' while asking about travel to the USA?

Comment: What's your nationality?

Comment: and why ARE YOU SHOUTING? No need to type in caps :/

Answer (score 2):

You typically need a passport to travel anywhere outside of your home country.

You need a visa (typically put *into* your passport) in order to enter the USA (or any other country, unless that country allows visa-free entry to citizens of your country).

So yes, you need both - a passport issued to you by your country, and a visa issued by the USA in that passport.